# Perl Regex and process check

Tags: regex, perl, file

I have a number of files in a certain directory, they are lock files.

I need to put together a perl script that will

**a: check for the file's in existance**

```
my @files = glob "/local/mnt/bin/log/*.lock";

for (@files){
  print "$_\r\n";
}
```

prints /local/mnt/bin/log/cron_1.***amd64***_.lock

**b: check for a running process with this file**

This links to the following process

/bin/ksh /local/mnt/bin/a.b/jobrunner -cron -o ***amd64***

I'm having trouble with the regex syntax to pull out the ***amd64*** part from the .lock file

**c: remove the file if there is no running process.**

I need to reference the job id in field $3 of the PID line, and check if that job exists, if not, then remove the file.

Any ideas with the regex bit, the "." seems to work as a wildcard, so I'm not sure how to escape it.

Thanks again, 
Ben

Comment: Why are you sticking a `\r` on the end of your print? And ... there's no regex in what you posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract `amd64` from: `/local/mnt/bin/log/cron_1.amd64_.lock`:

```
my $str = '/local/mnt/bin/log/cron_1.amd64_.lock';
my ( $thing ) = $str =~ m/\.(\w+)\.lock/;
```

This will make `$thing` `amd64_`. Alternatively you could use:

```
my ( $thing ) = $str =~ m/\.(\w+)_\.lock/;
```

You're right - in regex `.` is a wildcard. You escape it with a backslash. In the above, it'll match a literal `.`. `\w` is perl regex for "word characters" which is alphanumeric + underscore.

Comment: Wow, looks so simple when you put it this way, thanks for that, I couldn't find it online.  :)

Comment: The thing to watch out for - `my $thing = $str =~ m/\.(\w+)\.lock/;` won't do the same thing. You need those brackets around the left hand side because of context.

Comment: Used this, as the regex wouldnt work for me  <pre> <code>
      my @thing = split(/\./, "$str");
      print "$thing[1]\n";
      my $str2 = $thing[1]; 
      $str2 =~ s/[_]//g;
      
      print "$str2\n";  </code> </pre>

Comment: Be aware - arrays in perl start at `0`. So you probably want `$thing[0]` if you want the first match.

Comment: Thanks, yep it's [1] I meant to use :)